# Recreate background image infobar with HTML/CSS (Responsive)

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to recreate the background image used in this [example](http://www.flamingoland.co.uk/zoo-and-conservation/zoo/birds/184-cattle-egret.html/#threat-status). As you can currently see it is just using a class and some positioning to display the relevant threat icon. I need to recreate this using just HTML & CSS and make it work responsively, but i'm struggling where to start or what would be the best practice to provide a cross browser solution that is responsive.

I'm open to it changing if needs be, the main thing is it displays the information clearly. Obviously it will need to work on smaller resolutions where it could maybe stack on top or display in two rows of three etc. I have tried searching on Google for inspiration, but it's bringing mixed or irrelevant results possibly due to my incorrect search phrasing.

Closest thing I can seem to find are progress bars. I have uploaded the image to [this codepen example](http://codepen.io/CJG1979/pen/vLpWVo)

```
<div class="main-content" data-off-canvas-content>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="medium-12 columns">
     <h2>Threat Level</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint molestiae dolorum doloremque veritatis necessitatibus cumque nulla optio dolor, aspernatur libero facere, illum, minima saepe. Repellendus neque hic, laudantium impedit veritatis.</p>
   </div>
    <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/9bao4c64p/threat_status.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  </div>
```

If anyone can point me in the direction of a code solution/snippet or similar tutorial/further reading I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbxOBV

Please look at the css and read up on position and backgrounds.
The key to this method is that the container has the image set as a background and the background size is sized so the it gets cut of below the bar, so only the bar is visible.
Then the element containing the circle is placed ABSOLUTE (parent is therefore set to relative) so that it can be placed with absolute coordinated inside it's parent element.
Then you just "cut out" the part of the image you want.

You do that so you only have to load one image and can use it at multiple places and that saves a lot of bandwidth. Nice effort by the programmer.

HTML:

```
<div class="main-content" data-off-canvas-content>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
      <h2>Threat Level</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint molestiae dolorum doloremque veritatis necessitatibus cumque nulla optio dolor, aspernatur libero facere, illum, minima saepe. Repellendus neque hic, laudantium impedit veritatis.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="barContainer">
        <span class="threatLevel">
        </span>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.barContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 590px;
  height: 31px;
  background-image: url(http://s2.postimg.org/9bao4c64p/threat_status.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 44px 0 56px;  
}

.threatLevel {
   background: url(http://s2.postimg.org/9bao4c64p/threat_status.png) 0 -31px no-repeat;
   position: absolute;
   width: 98px;
   height: 90px;
   top: -31px;
}
```

Then change the CSS to:

```
.threatLevel {
   background: url(http://s2.postimg.org/9bao4c64p/threat_status.png) -100px -31px no-repeat;
   position: absolute;
   width: 98px;
   height: 90px;
   top: -31px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

and see what happens.

Comment: P.S.: play around with the parameters in .threatLevel background-image  to see how you can cut out and place the image.

Comment: Thanks Captain Quirk for your reply and link. I apologise maybe I did not word the question that well, I understand how the original effect was created, but I need to try and recreate it using html and css so it's fully responsive and works across as many browsers as possible. Just shrinking down the image makes it unreadable on small devices, so I need a solution that can reflow it and keep the information readable, if that makes sense.

Comment: Then you will have to do different graphics and just defined breakpoints.
You can then hide and show elements according to your breakpoints.